# Finding The Table With The Most Recent Creation Date

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a function to find the most recently created table object in an excel workbook (or I guess worksheet would do).

Running the code below returns the following:

> `Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method`

I don't understand why but it showing the error to be on line 12. I believe it to be in the "tbl.Created", however this is used on line 11 as well with no issue.

```vb
Sub TableWorx()
      ' Get the name of most recent Table (existing table on new sheet)
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim tbl As ListObject
  Dim newestObjectCreatedTime As Date
  Dim eTableName As String
  newestObjectCreatedTime = #1/1/1900# 'this is Excel's date with serial no of 0
  
  For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      For Each tbl In ws.ListObjects
        If tbl.Created > newestObjectCreatedTime Then
              newestObjectCreatedTime = tbl.Created
              eTableName = tbl.Name
          End If
      Next tbl
  Next ws
  MsgBox "The latest table object: " & eTableName
  'eventually will add code to set new table name, it may end up in a separate sub
End Sub
```

Any suggestions how to get this or an equivalent function working? I am feeling like an ignoramus here.

Attempted running the above code as a function in a module, as a part of an existing function int "ThisWorkbook", as an independent function in "ThisWorkbook".

keep coming back to this error:

> `Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject#properties  ListObjects don't have a `Created` property?

Comment: AFAIK Excel doesn't store this information.

Comment: On a 'worksheet level', you could possibly use the simple (no loop necessary): `eTableName = ws.ListObjects(ws.Listobjects.Count).Name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the `ListObject` doesn't have a `.Created` method nor property, so to directly get what you want isn't possible.

However, with a few assumptions (limitations) you can still figure this out.  Every time a table is added to a workbook, it gets a default name in the format "Table#".  # is the number of the table.  So the first table in a workbook has the default name of Table1, the second has the default name of Table2, and so on.  So, if all of the tables in a workbook are using their default names, then the table with the largest number in its name is the last one created.  (Note that if you create a table, and then delete it, the next table will still increment its name.  For example, if I have two tables in a workbook, and delete Table1, the next table I create will have the name Table3.)

So:

- Iterate through all sheets
- Get the last `ListObject` on each sheet
- Track the table numbers
- Return the largest (newest) table

```
Private Function GetLastTable() As ListObject

    ' Purpose:
    ' Return the most recently created Table, assuming all Tables are using default names
    
    Dim largestTableNumber As Long, tableName As String, tableNumber As Long, lastTable As ListObject
    
    ' Iterate through all worksheets
    Dim ii As Long
    For ii = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        
        ' The last object in the ListObjects is the most recently created table
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ii)
            tableName = .ListObjects(.ListObjects.Count).Name
        End With
        
        ' Get the table's default number
        tableNumber = Replace(tableName, "Table", "")
        
        ' If this number is larger than the one in storage, this table was created more recently
        If tableNumber > largestTableNumber Then
            largestTableNumber = tableNumber
            Set lastTable = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ii).ListObjects("Table" & tableNumber)
        End If
        
    Next ii

    Set GetLastTable = lastTable

End Function
```

Of course, error handling has been omitted here and the whole thing is based on some potentially prohibitive assumptions, but it's the best way I can think to try to get this info.